# How to integrate AVFoundation in a flutter project?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I am trying to integrate AVFoundation in my flutter project to scan QR code. I have followed the docs and wrote the following code

```
class CealScanQrView extends StatelessWidget {
  const CealScanQrView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> creationParams = <String, dynamic>{};
    return Platform.isAndroid
        ? AndroidView(
            viewType: cealScanQrView,
            layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            creationParams: creationParams,
            creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
          )
        : UiKitView(
            viewType: cealScanQrView,
            layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            creationParams: creationParams,
            creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
          );
  }
}
```

I have created `CealScanViewNativeViewFactory`, `CealScanViewNativeView` and registered in my `AppDelegate` using below code

```
weak var registrar = self.registrar(forPlugin: "ceal-views")
        let cealQrViewfactory = CealQrViewNativeViewFactory(messenger: registrar!.messenger())
        let viewRegistrar = self.registrar(forPlugin: "<ceal-views>")!
        viewRegistrar.register(
            cealQrViewfactory,
            withId: "cealQrView")
```

Below is my `CealScanViewNativeView` code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CealScanViewNativeView: NSObject, FlutterPlatformView,AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    
    private var _view: UIView
    
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    init(
        frame: CGRect,
        viewIdentifier viewId: Int64,
        arguments args: Any?,
        binaryMessenger messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger?
    ) {
        _view = UIView()
        super.init()
        setUpView()
    }
    
    func view() -> UIView {
        return _view
    }
    
    private func setUpView(){
        
        _view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = _view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        _view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        self.captureSession.startRunning()
        
    }
    
    func failed() {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Scanning not supported", message: "Device does not support scanning", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
        UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.flatMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.windows ?? [] }
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }?.rootViewController?.present(ac, animated: true)
        captureSession = nil
    }
    
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
        
        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
            guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
            guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            found(code: stringValue)
        }
        UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.flatMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.windows ?? [] }
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    
    func found(code: String) {
        debugPrint("Code is \(code)")
    }
    
}
```

I have given the camera permission as well but as soon as I open the view, I don't see the camera. I tried changing the  `_view.backgroundColor` to red and it is visible so the view is setup correctly but I don't get the camera. In my Xcode logs I see below warning

```
Thread Performance Checker: -[AVCaptureSession startRunning] should be called from background thread. Calling it on the main thread can lead to UI unresponsiveness
PID: 1107, TID: 125465
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
previewLayer.frame = _view.layer.bounds
```

use

```
previewLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,width: 200,height: 200)
```

Change `width` and `height` according to your needs

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are adding the `view` holding the preview layer to the hierarchy. Make sure you add it too.

There are a couple of things that you can do to make this work.

1. Session configuration takes time and it needs to be done on a separate serial queue, like so:

```
    private let sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "session queue")
    ...
    sessionQueue.async {
        self.setUpView()
    }
```

2. Make variables class properties, like so:

```
    private let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    private let metadataObjectsQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "metadata objects queue", attributes: [], target: nil)
```

3. Process output on a separate queue

```
    metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: metadataObjectsQueue)
    metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = metadataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes
```

4. Start session on the session queue

```
sessionQueue.async {
    if self.isSessionRunning {
        self.session.startRunning()
        self.isSessionRunning = self.session.isRunning
    }
}
```

You can find complete sample at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/avcambarcode_detecting_barcodes_and_faces

Comment: When you're creating a Native view in Flutter the default view is already present. You don't have to add it separately.  I no longer get the should be called from background thread error but I don't see the camera

Comment: @Pritish I would try changing the way you add video input, it looks like you are doing it differently than in the sample I linked.

Comment: I am following this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-scan-a-qr-code. It works in a native iOS project

Comment: I found the solution which I posted as an answer but your answer helped me to resolve the hand error. Thank you I am giving you the bounty

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is scanning qr code, why are you not using

https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner

Comment: I don't want to use third party lib. I want to learn how to use native views